# Two arguments in django-admin custom command

Tags: python, django, django-admin, arguments

I have a **working** django-admin custom command that I use to populate my database with new information. Again, everything works.

However, I have now changed my models and function slightly to accept two arguments as a tuple - first name **and** last name, instead of just "name".

Previous code below - working. Run using "manage.py xyz name1 name2 name3... etc. (space between the different args)

```
from django.core.management.base import BaseCommand, CommandError
from detail.models import ABC
from detail.parser import DEF

class Command(BaseCommand):
    args = '<name...>'
    help = 'Populates the ABC class database'

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        for symbol in args:

            try:
                info = DEF(name)
```

**Is it possible to pass on two arguments from the django-admin custom command where the second argument is optional --> i.e. (first, last=None)?**

Pseudocode below of what I'd like to run using... "manage.py xyz (first1, last1) (first2, last2) <-- or some variation of this

I've already changed the function DEF to accept this appropriately as a standalone function. I'm just not sure how I can get the django-admin command working now.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's entirely possible, although `django.core.management` does not provide a specific tool to do so. You can parse the arguments passed via the `args` keyword argument. You'll have to come up with a syntax for doing so (defining the syntax in the `help` attribute of the command would probably be a good idea).

Assuming the syntax is `firstname.lastname`, or just `firstname` in the case that the last name is omitted, you can do something like:

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    for arg in args:
        try:
            first_name, last_name = arg.split('.')
        except ValueError:
            first_name, last_name = arg, None

        info = DEF(first_name, last_name)
```

And users of the command can pass in arguments like so:

```
$ python manage.py yourcommand -v=3 john.doe bill patrick.bateman
```

Comment: THANKS! That worked well. I was originally hoping to have two separate args, but this works the same.

Comment: @modocache -v=3 ? what it will do ?

Comment: This answer is obsolete, django now has an `add_arguments` method built-in, which was added in v1.8. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/howto/custom-management-commands/