# Django Management Command Argument

Tags: python, django

I need to pass in an integer argument to a base command in Django. For instance, if my code is:

```
from django.core.management import BaseCommand

class Command(BaseCommand):
    def handle(self, *args, **options, number_argument):
        square = number_argument ** 2
        print(square)
```

I want to run:

```py
python manage.py square_command 4
```

so, it will return 16.

Is there a way I can pass an argument through the terminal to the command I want to run?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

Add this method to your Command class:

```
def add_arguments(self, parser):
    parser.add_argument('my_int_argument', type=int)
```

You can then use your option in the code, like this:

```
def handle(self, *args, **options):
    my_int_argument = options['my_int_argument']
```

The benefit of doing it this way is that the `help` output is automatically generated for `manage.py my_command --help`

Comment: Docs here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/

Comment: As of Django 2.8, this is the way to do it.

Comment: How can you add default value?

Comment: @EralpB just add a `defatult=<your default_value` kwarg to `parser.add_argument`

Comment: what is the purpose of *args then?

Comment: it's a standard pattern in Python to add *args and **kwargs: it ensures that when people inherit from this class you still can add extra keyword args in the function you override.

Answer (score 3):

Yes. The mechanism for doing so is described [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/), but basically, you can get the argument from `args[0]`.

Comment: Found a more complete answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10568864/two-arguments-in-django-admin-custom-command?rq=1

Comment: @PeterGraham now you should use the `add_arguments` method, which was added in version 1.8, so I wouldn't recommend that more complete answer anymore.

Answer (score 2):

This is pretty simple by implementing the `add_arguments` [method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/custom-management-commands/#django.core.management.BaseCommand.add_arguments). Then, you can get the value of this argument in the `handle` method as follows:

```py
class Command(BaseCommand):
    help = 'Help for command'

    def add_arguments(self, parser):
        parser.add_argument('n', type=int, help='help for n')

    def handle(self, *args, **options):
        n = options['n']
        square = n ** 2
        print(square)
```

The parameter `parser` is an instance of `argparse.ArgumentParser` (see [the docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method)). Now you can add as many arguments as you want by calling `parser`'s `add_argument` [method](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html#the-add-argument-method). In the code above, you are expecting a parameter `n` of type `int` which is gotten in the `handle` method from `options`.

If you want to see the help displayed, run the following:

```
python manage.py square_command --help
```

That will produce an output similar to the following one:

```
usage: manage.py create_documents [-h] [--version] [-v {0,1,2,3}] [--settings SETTINGS] [--pythonpath PYTHONPATH] [--traceback] [--no-color] [--force-color]
                                  [--skip-checks]
                                  n

Help for command

positional arguments:
  n                     help for n
```

Answer (score 0):

[django-typer](https://github.com/bckohan/django-typer) allows this to be specified more concisely than the BaseCommand class which uses argparse. The above could be rewritten:

```py
from django_typer import TyperCommand

class Command(TyperCommand):
    help = 'Help for command'

    def handle(self, n: int):
        print(n ** 2)
```